# why when I execute a select query on a view in vertica, do I get "Length for type varchar cannot exceed 65000"?

Tags: sql, view, vertica, flextable

I have a flextable in vertica and am trying to create a view based on it.

Here's the create view statement:

```
CREATE VIEW testview AS
    SELECT
            COALESCE (
                "USER_ID",
                "userId",
                "SM.actor.id",
                "SM.participant.userId",
                "SM.userId",
                "SM.uid",
                "SM_C.userId",
                "SM.id" )::varchar AS userid
    FROM
        flex_table_test
    WHERE "SM.verb" is not null
```

I can create the view successfully, but when I execute something like:

```
SELECT * FROM testview LIMIT 10;
```

I get:

> ERROR 3852:  Length for type varchar cannot exceed 65000

If I execute just the select part of the view by itself, it works fine.  I tried casting the output fields, but it doesn't seem to make much of a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, data in Flex tables are stored as `LONG VARBINARY` which has a default raw size of 130000. Since this data is longer than the maximum length for `VARCHAR` (65000), you need to either truncate the result of your `COALESCE` or try casting it as a `::long varchar`. If the latter works, be aware that Vertica does not support operations on this content type.

Comment: I was missing the size of the varchar in the cast, i.e. I changed "::varchar" to "::varchar(50)" and things started to work.  Thanks for the hints!